# Date values in CASE Statement

Tags: sql, db2

I get SQL Code -182 AN ARITHMETIC EXPRESSION WITH A DATETIME VALUE IS INVALID

when I try to run this snippet of code:

```
              (CASE
           WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2014
                THEN 0
          WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2015
                THEN 1
           WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2016
                THEN 2
               END) YEAR,
```

where R.CURR_PRD_NDT is a DATE value. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't quote numbers.  `When Year(R.Curr_Prd_Ndt) = 2014`

Comment: I tried that... no effect when I remove the quotes. Same error.

Comment: Which OS? Could you post the whole statement please?

Comment: Its DB2... more code added, but I doubt that will clarify things further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give `year` as alias name it will give you error try to change that to some other name

```
(CASE
WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2014
THEN 0
WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2015
THEN 1
WHEN YEAR(R.CURR_PRD_NDT) = 2016
THEN 2
END) as YEAR_value
```

Comment: Wow....I would never have thought that would cause a -182. It worked! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use YEAR as an alias; this is a reserved function name.